# JSON array in GSON parses, but objects are empty

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i am attempting to turn a json string into objects with gson.

I have a very simple example below, and it runs, but the resulting answer is empty, ie: my Answer objects's text field is empty.

```
import com.google.gson.*;

public class Meow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonOutput = "[{\"answer\":{\"text\":\"text1\"}},{\"answer\":{\"text\":\"text2\"}} ]";

        Answer[] a = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, Answer[].class);

        for(Answer i:a) {
          System.out.println(i.text);
        }       
    }

    public class Answer {

        public String text;

        public Answer(String text) {
            super();
            this.text=text;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String a){
            this.text=a;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your JSON doesn't match your class.

Your JSON right now is an array of objects, each containing an `answer` object as a field.

Your JSON the way you have things would need to look like:

```
String jsonOutput = "[{\"text\":\"text1\"},{\"text\":\"text2\"}]";
```

**Edit to add from comments:**

If you can't change the output, you need a "wrapper". Something like:

```
public class AnswerWrapper {
    public Answer answer;

    // etc
}
```

And use an array of those.  That is what the JSON will map to. It can't see them as `Answer` objects because ... they're not.

**One More Edit to Add:** Your other option is to write custom deserializers for your classes. I'm a bit mixed on whether you *should* do this or not, but it will work. The reason I say that is that you have JSON that *isn't* an array of `Answer` objects, but you want it to be. I think I'd be annoyed if I came across this in production code because without understanding what was going on it could be confusing.

With that caveat being said, you can create a custom `JsonDeserializer` and use `GsonBuilder`:

```
class AnswerDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Answer> {

    public Answer deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, 
                              JsonDeserializationContext jdc) 
                                   throws JsonParseException {

        return new Answer(je.getAsJsonObject().get("answer")
                            .getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString());
    }

}
```

Then your code would look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String jsonOutput = "[{\"answer\":{\"text\":\"text1\"}},{\"answer\":{\"text\":\"text2\"}} ]";

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Answer.class, new AnswerDeserializer());

    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    Answer[] a = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, Answer[].class);

    for(Answer i:a) {
        System.out.println(i.text);
    }       
}
```

If it were me, and I had JSON that wasn't what I needed it to be but wanted to use GSON to directly serialize/deserialize I'd create the `Answer` class as a wrapper that hid the details:

```
/**
 *  Due to how our JSON is being provided we created an inner
 *  class. 
 **/ 
public class Answer {

    private RealAnswer answer;

    private class RealAnswer {

        public String text;
    }

    ...
}
```

With the public getters/setters for `Answer` accessing the private `RealAnswer`. It just seems way cleaner and easier to understand for the next guy.

Comment: got it. unfortunately, there is no way i can change that output. how do I tell GSON that I would like these to be recognized as Answer objects? an update to your answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Brian! It works! But seems a tad weird, since i need to do this for all my files. I figure I could probably specify something for GSON?

Comment: @mingyeow -  
I added another section this morning. As noted, personally I'd not do it, but knowing it exists is in the spirit of SO.

Comment: this is an epic answer. thanks a million. i "get" gson a lot better now. thanks again!

Comment: btw, my inital json was implemented as such because of how Restkit in iOS expects this json. since learnt from implementing backbone and gson that it is not that smart to do so