# Objects are empty after parsing list with JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm currently trying to parse some JSON-Data using GSON:

```
[{
  "lvTypePathStr":  "teamList",
  "lvIDPathStr":    "155213",
  "lvTypeLabelStr": "\/ HSG Pinnau",

  "dataList": [{
    "lvTypeNext":     "",
    "lvIDNext":       0,
    "levelTypeLabel": "",
    "teamID":         "353197",
    "gClassID":       "22566",
    "gClassSname":    "M-HL",
    "clubSname":      "HSG Pinnau",
    "clubLname":      "HSG Pinnau",
    "teamSname":      "HSG Pinnau"
  }, {
    "lvTypeNext":     "",
    "lvIDNext":       0,
    "levelTypeLabel": "",
    "teamID":         "353226",
    "gClassID":       "22569",
    "gClassSname":    "M-BL-1",
    "clubSname":      "HSG Pinnau",
    "clubLname":      "HSG Pinnau",
    "teamSname":      "HSG Pinnau 2"
  }],
  "errCode": 0
}]
```

The according Objects are:
The list to hold all Teams:

```
public class JSONTeamList extends JSONResponse {


private List<JSONTeam> dataList = new ArrayList<JSONTeam>();

public List<JSONTeam> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
}

public void setDataList(List<JSONTeam> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
}
```

Inheiring from JSONResponse just for the common attributes:

```
public class JSONResponse {

protected String lvTypePathStr;
protected String lvIDPathStr;
protected String lvTypeLabelStr;
protected int errorCode;

/** ... getter and setter for all attributes ... */
}
```

And finally the Teams itself:

```
public class JSONTeam {

private String lvTypeNext;
private int lvIDNext;
private String levelTypeLabel;
private String teamID;
private String gClassID;
private String gClassSName;
private String clubSName;
private String clubLName;
private String teamSName;

/** Getter and setter for all attributes... */
}
```

I've omitted the getters and setters for better readability, but they are auto-generated using IntelliJ in the form get{variable} and set{variable} as usual.

The parsing code is:

```
URL url = new URL(baseURL + clubId);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
JSONTeamList[] list = gson.fromJson(in, JSONTeamList[].class);
```

Now when I parse the JSON, I get a Teamlist which is populated with teams but all attributes in the teams are empty. 
I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873324/json-array-in-gson-parses-but-objects-are-empty) question, but I don't think it matches this case because this is a nested list.
What did I miss to let GSON populate the Teams correctly?

Thanks in advance,
Sverre

Comment: provide your GSON parsing code, using gson.fromJson().

Comment: Added it, see edit.

Comment: The `dataList` isn't at the top-level, it's contained in the first element of the JSON. You need to first dip down into the outer array's elements, and each one of those (there's only one in this case) has the `lvTypePathStr` etc. and `dataList`. It looks like you're operating one level too high.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing by placing the dataList as an attribute in the JSONTeamList-Class? Or do I need to add another wrapper around it between the JSONTeamList and the actual list?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the uppercase in the variable names was wrong, e.g. `gClassSname` was variable `gClassSName` but should have been `gClassSname`.
Took me like two hours to realize it's that simple...